# Bootstrap 3.3.1 Modal Box pushes html content to left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I dont know why once I put the bootstrap modal into my page, the content will move to left, and return back to its position after the modal box closed.

This wont happen to short html page, only for long html page where there is a horizontall scrollbar..

Can anybody tell me what is happening?

I check bootstrap website but It didnt happen so.

I downloaded the newest version and did not change any of the modal css.

Comment: can you show us your code and maybe a screenshot of what happens

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to post a screenshot. If I put the code, it might be really long right?

Comment: can you upload your website to an online webserver or hosting so we can see real life what is happenening?

Comment: Sorry for asking too much, can you tell me which online webserver Sir? Never upload my website into an online webserver but only to my localhost

Comment: make a fiddle. http://www.bootply.com/new#

Comment: Make a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

You are likely encountering https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14040 , which is a known open bug.

Comment: This was problem with 3.2.0 in new version 3.3.1 is fixed